# why is $S^2$ not a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups

I'm reading John Stillwell's "Naive Lie Theory" and it was mentioned there (without giving a proper definition of what a Lie group is) that the only Lie groups among the unit n-spheres are $S^1$ and $S^3$.
Is there a simple or naive explanation of what makes $S^2$ so different from $S^1$ and $S^3$?

Comment: You should look at answers of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/809830/59379) and [that](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122707/which-topological-spaces-are-topological-groups), they tell you what sort of topological space is capable to turn into a  topological group.

Comment: Technically, $S^0$ is also a Lie group, but a lot of writers ignore the zero-dimensional case.

Comment: https://math.berkeley.edu/~seewoo5/S2notLiegrp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the comments on Hagen's answer, there are continuous self maps of $S^2$ with no fixed points (e.g., the antipodal map as Chris Z points outs), and orientation preserving homeomorphisms with only one fixed point (e.g., Mobius transformations as Max points out).

As Hagen rightly points out, on a Lie group, there are homeomorphisms which are homotopic to the identity, but which have no fixed points:  left multiplication by any non-identity element which lies in the identity component of the Lie group is an example.

So, to show $S^2$ is not a Lie group, it is sufficient to show that every homeomorphism of $S^2$ which is homotopic to the identity has a fixed point.  In fact, any continuous map (be it a homeomorphism or not) of $S^2$ has this property.
this is proved in [this MSE question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539506/mapping-homotopic-to-the-identity-map-has-a-fixed-point)  In fact, both Bruno Joyal's and Gyu Eun Lee's answers to that question generalize to prove that $S^{2n}$ is not a Lie group for any $n > 0$.